# CountIf Function does not count in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, countif

in Every cell in a Selection I need to replace a combination of characters. But before a replacement I want to count every combination.
The problem is that CountIf function won't count at all. Though replacement performs.

Here is a code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub sdfsdf()
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim Cell As Range
Dim Counter As Variant

'Application.Run "Personal.xlsb!Main"

Set rng = Selection
Set Cell = Cell
Let i = 1

For Each Cell In Selection
Let Counter = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Cell, i & "&")
Cell.Replace What:=i & "&", Replacement:=""
i = i + 1
Next Cell

MsgBox Counter
End Sub
```

A snippet of a column with combinations to delete. I need to delete 1&, 2&, 3& and so on.
[image]

Comment: Would you not require a counter=counter+counter formula?

Comment: `Set Cell = Cell` is redundant. The `Let` keyword is not used in VBA: just remove all occurrences. Please explain what exactly you are trying to count? Your code 'counts' (writes 1 to `Counter`) if the first cell is equal to `1&`, the second cell is equal to `2&`, ..., and replaces each occurrence in the cell and BTW making the cell blank (if true).

Comment: @VBasic2008 , I've added a snippet of a column with characters which need to be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Remove Characters

```vb
Sub RemoveChars()

    Const Criteria As String = "&"

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ws.Range("U2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp))
    ' Or:
    'Set rg = Selection
    
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim Position As Long
    Dim cCount As Long
    Dim cString As String
    
    For Each Cell In rg.Cells
        cString = CStr(Cell.Value)
        Position = InStr(1, cString, Criteria)
        If Position > 0 Then ' criteria found; replace with chars to the right
            Cell.Value = Mid(cString, Position + 1, Len(cString) - Position)
            cCount = cCount + 1
        'Else ' criteria not found; do nothing
        End If
    Next Cell

    MsgBox "Cells processed: " & cCount, vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
This code worked.
I also learnt new commands and correct code structure.
But there are two moments:
1) what if a cell contains two characters &. And I need to delete only the first occurrence.
2) your code counts number of cells, I need to count number of combination "digit & "&" ".

Comment: Both of your requirements are covered by the code: *1.)* `InStr(1, cString, Criteria)` (it is similar to Excel's `FIND` or `SEARCH` functions) returns the position of the first occurrence of `Criteria` in `cString` while *2.)* `If Position > 0 Then` covers only cells (cases) where `Criteria` was actually found.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Maybe you can also tell me why my code did not count cases. Counter = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Cell, i & "&")